# Invalid session after login into IBM Watson IoT Platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-iot

After login into IBM Watson IoT Platform. I get this error message.

```
Invalid session
The session is invalid or has expired. Repeat the process.
```

[image]

Logging out and logging in several times did not correct the error.

Yesterday I was still able to process data in the IBM Watson IoT Platform.

Why happens and how do I fix the error?

Comment: Independent of IBM Watson IoT Platform I would recommend to clear cookies and try it in a new (private) window.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another browser. I was using Safari and switched to Chrome. It works from there.